# Setinterval Animation sometime paused

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, setinterval

I make an animation using sequence images. i run the images using setinterval function animation going fine but i dont know why it paused some time. i posted fiddle here look this fiddle you can able to notice this pause

[**Unwanted Pause Happen Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Rjhx3/)

```
myAnim = setInterval(function(){
  $("#myImageHolder8").attr('src', nextImage5[u]);
  u++;
  if(u==nextImage5.length)
  {
    u=0;
  }
}, 50);
```

Pls friends Help me.

Comment: It worked fine for me? Could it possibly be you're just waiting for the images to load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to preload the image. Setting the image source inside the loop will definately cause a hick-up at one point as loading and decoding the image(s) may very well exceed 50 ms (cached or not). This will also cause the problem to appear randomly (and faster computers may not notice while slower one or slower connections may cause this more frequent).

Preload the images and the simply insert the loaded image into the container (a parent element) instead.

You can preload the images either by hiding them in DOM and use window.onload to start, or do it in JavaScript using an array and load counter.

An example of an loader:

### [Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/Rjhx3/1/)

```
var images = [],
    count = nextImage5.length,
    len = count,
    i = 0;

for(; i < len; i++) {
    var img = new Image;
    images.push(img);
    img.onload = loader;
    img.src = nextImage5[i];
}

function loader() {
    count--;
    if (count === 0) {
        ... start animation here...
    }
}
```

and then in the animation loop do something like (sorry, my jQuery escapes me but you see the point):

```
$('#myImageHolder8').html('');
$('#myImageHolder8').append(images[u]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before setting the animation, make sure you preload your images first. So that the images are ready and loaded to display smoothly. You can use this [preloader](https://github.com/farinspace/jquery.imgpreload). And I would like to suggest that instead of changing the src  of an `<img>` it is better to draw the image to a `<canvas>` then create a `<canvas>` for your next image.